# Matroid: another version of basis exchange property

Tags: combinatorics, matroids

Let $M$ be a matroid and $A,B$ be two bases of $M$. The *basis exchange property* tells us that for every $a\in A\setminus B$, there exists $b\in B\setminus A$ such that $(A\setminus \{a\})\cup \{b\}$ is a basis of $M$.

I wonder if the following statement is true:

There exists $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that both $(A\setminus \{a\})\cup \{b\}$ and $(B\setminus \{b\})\cup \{a\}$ are bases of $M$ (i.e., we swap $a$ and $b$).

If not, do we have a counterexample?

Or even stronger: what if we just let $A,B$ to be two independent sets with the same cardinality?

Comment: For the first question: Yes; it's called the "symmetric basis exchange property". I don't have a quick reference handy, but I think it's in [Lex Schrijver's *Course in Combinatorial Optimization*](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/dict.pdf). For the second question: Yes, and this follows from the first question, since you can truncate a matroid $M$ at an arbitrary integer $k\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,\operatorname{rank} M\right\}$, and the bases of the resulting matroid will be the independent $k$-sets of $M$. Someone with more time can hopefully elaborate on both of these.

Comment: References [2], [5] and [7] in [Harold Gabow, *Decomposing symmetric exchanges in matroid bases*. Mathematical Programming, **10** (1), 271--276, 1976](https://sci-hub.se/https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01580672) supposedly have proofs of the symmetric basis exchange property.